# Connect Pentaho to Azure Blob storage

Tags: azure, pentaho, azure-blob-storage

I was recently thrown into dealing with databases and Microsoft Azure Blob storage.
As I am completely new to this field I have some troubles:
I can't figure out how to connect to the Blob storage from Pentaho and I could not find any good information online on this topic either.

I would be glad for any information on how to set up this connection.

Comment: Could you please show us what you have already tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the core-site.xml like so: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_cloud-data-access/content/authentication-wasb.html

This will give you access to the azure blob storage account.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the file in Azure Blob and Generate SAS token and URL and copy the URL only. In PDI, select Hadoop file input. Double click the Hadoop file input and select local for the Evironment and insert the Azure URL in File/Folder field and that's it. You should see the file in PDI.

Comment: I just did it and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out eventually.

Pentaho provides a HTTP element, in which you can, amongst other things specify an URL.

In Microsoft Azure Blob storage you can generate a SAS token. If you use the URL made from the storage **resource URI** and the **SAS token** as input for the URL field in the HTTP element, Pentaho can access the respective file in the Blob storage.